# How to use the w command of sed and write to file?

Tags: sed

Below is my testing. How can I fix the error?

```
ubuntu@u1804:~# sed --version
sed (GNU sed) 4.5
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <https://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Jay Fenlason, Tom Lord, Ken Pizzini,
and Paolo Bonzini.
GNU sed home page: <https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/>.
General help using GNU software: <https://www.gnu.org/gethelp/>.
E-mail bug reports to: <bug-sed@gnu.org>.
ubuntu@u1804:~#
ubuntu@u1804:~# cat test
11
aa
bb
cc
edde
xx
aa
bb
cc
edde
22
ubuntu@u1804:~# sed -r '/^[a-z]/{s/^.*$/(&)/; w result}' test
sed: -e expression #1, char 0: unmatched `{'
ubuntu@u1804:~#
ubuntu@u1804:~# sed -r '/^[a-z]/{s/^.*$/(&)/; p}' test
11
(aa)
(aa)
(bb)
(bb)
(cc)
(cc)
(edde)
(edde)
(xx)
(xx)
(aa)
(aa)
(bb)
(bb)
(cc)
(cc)
(edde)
(edde)
22
ubuntu@u1804:~#
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check your working directory, you might have a file named `result}` created

```
sed -r -e '/^[a-z]/{s/^.*$/(&)/; w result' -e '}' test
```

There are different ways to work around, one of them is to use `-e` option to separate the commands. When `w` is used, all the characters after it is used for filename and hence why you got the error as `{` didn't have an ending pair

Further reading: [GNU sed manual: Commands Requiring a newline](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Commands-Requiring-a-newline)

Comment: Oh, yes. There is a file called result}. Thanks for your answer.